# How to straighten curved line using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have image with curved line like this :

[image]

I couldn't find a technique to straighten curved line using OpenCV. It is similar to this post [Straightening a curved contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645077/straightening-a-curved-contour), but my question is specific to coding using opencv (in C++ is better).

So far, I'm only able to find the contour of the curved line.

[image]

```
int main()
{
    Mat src; Mat src_gray;
    src = imread("D:/2.jpg");
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(1, 15));

    Canny(src_gray, src_gray, 100, 200, 3);
    /// Find contours   
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RNG rng(12345);
    findContours(src_gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    /// Draw contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(src_gray.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, (255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }

    imshow("Result window", drawing);
    imwrite("D:/C_Backup_Folder/Ivan_codes/VideoStitcher/result/2_res.jpg", drawing);

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

But I have no idea how to determine which line is curved and not, and how to straighten it. Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

Before everything, resize your image into a much bigger image (for example 5 times bigger). Then do what you did before,  and get the contours. Find the right-most pixel of each contour, and then survey all pixel of that contour and count the horizontal distance of each pixels to the right-most pixel and make a shift for that row (entire row). This method makes a right shift to some rows and left shift to the others.

If you have multiple contours, calculate this shift value for every one of them in every single row and compute their "mean" value, and do the shift according to that mean value for each row.

At the end resize back your image. This is the simplest and fastest thing I could think of.